# Finding the solutions to some partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given functions $x_1,x_2,x_3:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which are differentiable, $x_1(0)=0$ and for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $x_2(t)>0$, I want to find the differentiable functions $u:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ which solve the equation $$(\partial_1u)(x_1,x_2,x_3)+x_1x_2(\partial_2u)(x_1,x_2,x_3)+2x_1^2\log(x_2)x_3(\partial_3u)(x_1,x_2,x_3)=0.$$

So to the best of my understanding, I'm supposed to proceed as follows:

Assume $$x_1'=1, \ x_2'=x_1x_2, \ x_3'=2x_1^2\log(x_2)x_3.$$ Then by integration and the fact that $x_1(0)=0$, we obtain that there are $s_2,s_3\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $$x_1(t)=t,$$ $$x_2(t)=s_2\exp(t^2/2),$$ $$x_3(t)=s_3\exp(t^5/5+2\log(s_2)t^3/3).$$ So $x_1$ is the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$ and we have $$x_2=s_2\exp(x_1^2/2),$$ $$x_3=s_3\exp(x_1^5/5+2\log(s_2)x_1^3/3).$$ The problem now is that it is unclear to me how to proceed, or if this is the end, and why (which I'm fairly sure it is not, since I don't see a solution yet).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I now understand what I have to do:

Let the functions $x_1,x_2,x_3:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and such that $\text{im}x_2\subseteq\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and $$x_1'=1, \ x_2'=x_1x_2, \ x_3'=2x_1^2(\log \circ x_2)x_3.$$ By integration, there are $c_1,c_2,c_3\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $$x_1(t)=t+c_1,$$ $$x_2(t)=\exp(t^2/2+c_1t+c_2),$$ $$x_3(t)=\exp(t^5/5+c_1t^4+(5c_1^2/3+2c_2/3)t^3+(c_1^3+2c_1c_2)t^2+(2c_1^2c_2)t+c_3).$$ Assume now $$0=x_1(0)=c_1$$ and define $$s_2=x_2(0)=\exp(c_2),$$ $$s_3=x_3(0)=\exp(c_3).$$ Note than that for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $$x_1(t)=t,$$ $$x_2(t)=s_2\exp(\frac{t^2}{2}),$$ $$x_3(t)=s_3\exp(-\frac{2t^5}{15}+\frac{2t^3\log(x_2(t))}{3}).$$ In particular, $$x_2\exp(\frac{-x_1^2}{2}), x_3\exp(\frac{2x_1^5}{15}-\frac{2x_1^3(\log \circ x_2)}{3})$$ are constant functions. Define then $u:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $$u(t_1,t_2,t_3)=(t_2\exp(\frac{-t_1^2}{2}),t_3\exp(\frac{2t_1^5}{15}-\frac{2t_1^3\log(t_2)}{3})),$$ and consider any diffeentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Observe that for the projection functions $t_1,t_2,t_3:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, we have $$\partial_1(f \circ u)+t_1t_2\partial_2(f \circ u)+2t_1^2t_3(\log \circ t_2)\partial_3(f \circ u) =$$ $$(\partial_1 f \circ u)(\partial_1 u_1) + (\partial_2 f \circ u)(\partial_1 u_2) +$$ $$t_1t_2[(\partial_1 f \circ u)(\partial_2 u_1) + (\partial_2 f \circ u)(\partial_2 u_2)] +$$ $$2t_1^2t_3(\log \circ t_2)[(\partial_1 f \circ u)(\partial_3 u_1) + (\partial_2 f \circ u)(\partial_3 u_2)] =$$ $$(\partial_1 f \circ u)(-t_1t_2\exp(\frac{-t_1^2}{2})) + (\partial_2 f \circ u)(t_3\exp(\frac{2t_1^5}{15}+\frac{-2t_1^3(\log \circ t_2)}{3})(\frac{2t_1^4}{3}-2t_1^2(\log \circ t_2))) +$$ $$t_1t_2[(\partial_1 f \circ u)(\exp(\frac{-t_1^2}{2})) + (\partial_2 f \circ u)(t_3\exp(\frac{2t_1^5}{15}+\frac{-2t_1^3(\log \circ t_2)}{3})(\frac{-2t_1^3}{3t_2}))] +$$ $$2t_1^2t_3(\log \circ t_2)[(\partial_1 f \circ u)(0) + (\partial_2 f \circ u)(\exp(\frac{2t_1^5}{15}+\frac{-2t_1^3(\log \circ t_2)}{3}))] = 0.$$